# Iterate thought JSON object and get specific properties

Tags: c#, json

I'm having trouble to properly iterate with the json response i got. There's no specific id/key to loop them.

First here is my sample json object.
The key's of json is id and is dynamic.

[Sample JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1U6I.png)

```
{
"1": {
    "docid": "26",
    "title": "QT1030-3 Product Development Plan Template",
    "category": "Template/Form",
    "children": {}
},
"2": {
    "docid": "27",
    "title": "QT1030-2 Product Requirements Template",
    "category": "Template/Form",
    "children": {}
},
"3": {
    "docid": "28",
    "title": "QT1030-1 Product Specifications Template",
    "category": "Template/Form",
    "children": {}
},
"60": {
    "docid": "22",
    "title": "QT1030-7 Design & Development Review Template",
    "category": "Template/Form",
    "children": {}
},
"61": {
    "docid": "23",
    "title": "QT1030-6 Design Inputs Outputs Matrix",
    "category": "Template/Form",
    "children": {}
},
"63": {
    "docid": "24",
    "title": "QT1030-5 DHF Index Template",
    "category": "Template/Form",
    "children": {}
},
"82": {
    "docid": "25",
    "title": "QT1030-4 Material Specifications",
    "category": "Template/Form",
    "children": {}
}
```

Here i tried to loop dynamic but not sure how to iterate properly. 
I tried something like item.docid but no success.

C# code

[C# Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BTkL.png)

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var documents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic nodelist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(documents);

    foreach (var item in nodelist)
    {
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you can iterate it and get value of `docid` as follow:

```
dynamic nodeList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(documents);

foreach (JProperty node in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Value["docid"]);
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, I marked your answer correct. But i have another question. How about the children? assuming it has the same docid, title and category.

Comment: i tried item.Value["children"].ToObject<Children>() but all returns null

Comment: try `(item.Value["children"] as JObject)` to get children object, for example for category property of children would be `(item.Value["children"] as JObject)["category"]`